# AWS Aurora replication - is that possible to lose data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-replication, amazon-aurora

I'm confused about AWS Aurora (mostly MySQL interests me).

I know that Aurora separates the storage layer from the compute layer, but this is what makes me dizzy.

From the documentation it appears that the data is saved in 6 copies between AZs in the region - these 6 copies are saved synchronously.

However, in the case of an Aurora instance (read replica, reader, whatever you want to call it) - replication is asynchronous.

Asynchronous to me is equivalent to the fact that you can lose data, after all. Can someone explain in a simple enough way what it is in the end with the potential loss of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lag in Aurora replicas is in [milliseconds](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/faqs/) and it does not lead to any data lose. It simply means that you have to wait few milliseconds before newly written data will be available in read replicas. All data is still stored across several AZs in multiple copies.

Comment: But both primary instance and read replica instance use the same shared storage, so how this lag is coming into the picture?